# Iteration enabled only for Tooltip, not also for button

Tags: thymeleaf

I am wondering if there is an option to do iteration for data only stored as Tooltip data? The result is that i get one button and one object from loop in tooltip. Is it possible to make button be one, and all data will be printed in tooltip?

I want to print in tooltip user nicks who liked post. All nicks are in "likes".
Code:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="like : ${likes}">
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" style="color:white"
                   th:href="@{'/like/' + ${temp.id}}"
                   data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" th:title="${like.userNick}">Like
                    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> <span class="badge badge-light">
                      <span th:text="${temp.likes}"/></span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have all the information for the tooltip in the title to be able to render that. One way is to build a `likesStr` in the server which can be used directly in the HTML wihtout the need for loop. Like (compatible with Java 8 onwards) :

```
model.put("likesStr", likes.stream()
   .map(like -> like.getUserNick())
   .join(Collectors.joining(","));

//then in the HTML:
<a class="btn btn-primary" style="color:white"
   th:href="@{'/like/' + ${temp.id}}"
   data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" th:title="${likesStr}">Like
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> <span class="badge badge-light">
      <span th:text="${temp.likes}"/></span>
</a>
```

But if its a lot of information, showing it as a tooltip will not be user friendly.

Also there are other variables used in the HTML like `${temp}` which dont appear how they are declared. So if you need more better assitance please provide a better HTML snippet along with the structure of Java model.

Comment: Hey MohamedSanaulla! Thanks for answer. Yeah, that works, but i wanted to refresh list of users who liked after every click "like" button. That way it only loads after loading main page. Anyways, it works. Thank you.

Comment: And yes it displays in every file all likes from all files. Is it possible also to dinamically filter id by "fileId"?